# C# cannot convert from "Gameserver.Client.TCP" to "Sytem.Net.Sockets.TcpClient"

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I am trying to set up a test server for a simple Game and I am following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh8XaC0Y5MA). The problematic bit of code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace GameServer
{
    class Client
    {
        public static int dataBufferSize = 4096;
        public int id;
        public TcpClient tcp;

        public Client(int _clientId)
        {
            id = _clientId;
            tcp = new TCP(id);
        }

        public class TCP
        {
            public TcpClient socket;

            private readonly int id;
            private NetworkStream stream;
            private byte[] receiveBuffer;

            public TCP(int _id)
            {
                id = _id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program I get the error from the title because of this block of code(precisely the "new TCP(id)" Part):

```
public Client(int _clientId)
{
    id = _clientId;
    tcp = new TCP(id);
}
```

From my understanding the problem is that I cant convert from the Self written code to the standard library but I don't see where that would be a problem.
So my question is: is there a conversion I can use or some other solution to my problem.
Thank you in advance.
PS. If you need more of the source code please write a Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your field `tcp` is defined as the type TCPClient, not as type TCP.  There's a type mismatch.  Which type did you want it to be?

You need to fix either the type behind `new`, or the type in the definition of your field.  Based on the structure (that type TCP contains a TCPClient inside), you wanted the field `tcp` to be of type TCP.  So change `public TCPClient tcp;` to `public TCP tcp;`.